# print each row of dates or data in a dataframe one by one passing it to a function

Tags: function, datetime, pandas

I have a dataframe with some start and end dates which I would like to pass row by row i.e. pairs of start and end dates to the function.

```
Data
start       | end 
2015-06-01    2016-06-28
.
.
.
```

I want to be able to pass an entire row of a dataframe or certain columns from a dataframe to a function and the function repeats over all the rows separately.

I have only been able to get .apply and .applymap in pandas working on a single column from a dataframe but not multiple or all columns in a dataframe (or just the number of columns passed to the function).

Answer (score 2):

If you're just iterating through the rows you should use [`iterrows`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html):

```
In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], columns=["A", "B"])

In [12]: df
Out[12]:
   A  B
0  1  2
1  3  4

In [13]: for i, row in df.iterrows():
             print(row)

A    1
B    2
Name: 0, dtype: int64
A    3
B    4
Name: 1, dtype: int64
```

You can restrict to some columns with `[[...]]`:

```
In [14]: df[["A"]]
Out[14]:
   A
0  1
1  3
```

---

You can use apply on rows rather than columns by passing [axis=1](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
In [21]: df.apply(lambda row: row.sum(), axis=1)
Out[21]:
0    3
1    7
dtype: int64
```

Note: In this case you can use the native pandas sum function, but when writing your own functions they can take a row (as a Series):

```
In [31]: df.sum(axis=1)   # much faster
Out[31]:
0    3
1    7
dtype: int64

In [32]: df.apply(print, axis=1)  # python 3 (print is a function)
A    1
B    2
Name: 0, dtype: int64
A    3
B    4
Name: 1, dtype: int64
Out[32]:
0    None
1    None
dtype: object
```

Comment: thanks @andyHayden but how do you pass a dataframe row, and each row thereafter using iterrows to a python function. I have a function yahoo_prices() which takes 3 arguments, a stock name, start date and end date which are in three columns in a pandas dataframe. I could filter out only the columns I need using the [[]] syntax but I'm not sure how to pass (for example in one row, the A column as one parameter, and the B column as another parameter to a function).

Comment: In the above, the row is being passed to the print function. If you want to access a specific row entry (column) in a row, use the loc or iloc. e.g. `for row in df.iterrows():  yahoo_prices(row.loc["start"], row.loc["end"], ...)`, I think you can also use `row["start"]`.

Comment: when I try this I get the error "tuple' object has no attribute 'loc"

Comment: the only way I could get it working was hacking together this for loop, but I'd really rather just pass every intersection of a row for a few particular row/columns straight to the function. It's a hacky workaround and I have to convert it to a dataframe and merge it but it works. for i in range(0,dates.shape[0]):
    prettyrow(dates["start_date"][i],dates["end_date"][i])

Comment: @yoshiserry tuple? row should be a Series! In the above example both `row["A"]` and `row.loc["A"]` both work.

Comment: @yoshiserry ooooh!! Sorry, my example in the comment was incorrect (it was correct in the answer), iterrows also gives an (index, row) tuple, so do: `for i, row in df.iterrows(): ...`